# Order mat-grid-tile based on screen size

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to mat-grid-list and mat-grid-tile components of Angular and trying to create a nice dashboard with it. I have read through docs and examples https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples.

What I am missing is a possibility to order the tiles based on the device.

For example. If I have 5 cards and in full screen it looks like this:
[image]

Then when I switch to mobile I want the order to be like this:
[image]

In Bootstrap you have the css-classes "order-", do you have something similar that can be used for the mat-grid-list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate you Card 3. Add condition to the duplicate as follows:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngIf="card3Reordered">...</mat-grid-tile>
```

Do the same in your first Card 3 but invert it:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngIf="!card3Reordered">...</mat-grid-tile>
```

In your `component.ts`, declare the variable:

```
card3Reordered: boolean;
```

Do `implements AfterViewInit` as follows:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.XSmall]).subscribe((res) => {
    if (res.matches) {
      this.card3Reordered = true;
    } else {
      this.card3Reordered = false;
    }
  });
}
```